# Is it possible to put 'number of chosen checkboxes limitation' in multiple forms into the loop?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops, checkbox

I'am creating a page on which the user will fill form consisting of multiple forms. Each of these forms has different maximal number of possible answers. How to minimize the number of lines of code and put this code into the loop? I tried to do the loop based on array, but i still don't know how to change `$("input[name='Pytanie1']")` every time the loop goes through it. The javascript I would like to put into the loop:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[name='Question1']").change(function () {
                var maxAllowed = 2; 
                var cnt = $("input[name='Question1']:checked").length;
                if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
                    $(this).prop("checked", "");
                    alert('Choose max. ' + maxAllowed + ' answers!');
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[name='Question2']").change(function () {
                var maxAllowed = 3; 
                var cnt = $("input[name='Question2']:checked").length;
                if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
                    $(this).prop("checked", "");
                    alert('Choose max. ' + maxAllowed + ' answers!');
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[name='Question3']").change(function () {
                var maxAllowed = 3; 
                var cnt = $("input[name='Question3']:checked").length;
                if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
                    $(this).prop("checked", "");
                    alert('Choose max. ' + maxAllowed + ' answers!');
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why put this in a loop? I'm not sure what you mean? And your code definitely calls for refactoring as you have duplicated lines for every question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You could simply create an array of max allowed values :

```
var maxAllowed = [2, 3, 3];
```

and iterate :

```
for (var i = 0; i < maxAllowed.length; i++) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var j = i;
        $("input[name='Question" + (j + 1) + "']").change(function () {
            var cnt = $("input[name='Question" + (j + 1) + "']:checked").length;
            if (cnt > maxAllowed[j]) {
                $(this).prop("checked", "");
                alert('Choose max. ' + maxAllowed[j] + ' answers!');
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Edit : There seemed to be a closure error in my previous code. Sorry

Comment: Unofrtunetaly your code does not work. I dont know why, because it seems to be OK. I thought that there might be some issues with quotation marks, but it does not work either :/

Answer (score 0):

### A reusable HTML-driven solution

I've [created a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/UzEA4/2) that uses `data-` HTML attributes to provide maximum value and reusable jQuery code that could be put on any page that requires it or could be changed into a jQuery plugin.

#### This is HTML I used

```
<div class="q" data-max="3">
    <h3>Question 1 with max 3</h3>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 1</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 2</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 3</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 4</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 5</input>
</div>
<div class="q" data-max="2">
    <h3>Question 2 with max 2</h3>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 1</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 2</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 3</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 4</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox">Answer 5</input>
</div>
```

#### And Javascript that drives it

```
$(".q").each(function(){
    $(this).data("selected", 0);
});

$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(evt){
    var q = $(this).closest(".q");

    if (this.checked && q.data("max") === q.data("selected"))
    {
        alert("You can choose at most " + q.data("max") + " answers");
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    q.data("selected", q.data("selected") + (this.checked ? 1 : -1));
});
```